# Typescript - Restrict values of object keys to some possible values, but don't make them mandatory

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, partial, keyof

I've got some types defined as:

```
export const ABC= {
  A: 'A',
  B: 'B',
  C: 'C',
} as const;

export const DEF = {
  D: 'D',
  E: 'E',
  F: 'F',
} as const;

export type AbcTypes = (typeof ABC)[keyof typeof ABC];
export type DefTypes = (typeof DEF)[keyof typeof DEF];
```

Now, I'd like to create an object that can have only values present in those types as keys, but it doesn't need to have them all, so I'm writing the following:

```
type MyNewDictionary = {
  [pKey in AbcTypes]: {
    [eKey in DefTypes]: {
      onClick: () => void;
      onCancel: () => void;
    }
  }
};
...
const dictionary: MyNewDictionary = {
  [ABC.A]: {
    [DEF.D]: {
      onClick: () => null,
      onCancel: () => null,
    }
  }
};
```

However, whenever I try to set some of these object keys, it complains because the rest are missing:

```
Type: { D: { onClick: () => void; onCancel: () => void; } } is missing the following properties from type: ...
```

I've tried using `Partial` and using `keyof`, with the same results.

Here you can see [a working Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAggIQMIF4YG8BQN4C4YDkcBANNjAvgQqeUlUrQL4wCGEMokUA3Jpl2gwAIgFEAYjDRYcwqsNo5RVUYpjiq45mw6De-KAE8ADgFN4AI2AAVE6Y5oAFEbMgAZvGQBKANoBrU0N3GBdTYMQkAF0%20UJFTN1szBxhnO2CxcV8AoI9Q9IlogzsYAFlDADlTAHdhAEtgKFrwVgAnQykMch9jAGlAmFqwSxs7CEj8GRwYH1M%209sG4hNHxzqmp8CQAG3q-fEcvKQA%20GAA3EFqAEz41nA3WMGBTTb2DlGOzy%20uppnIfpj4BOAhBd6o1mm18GVKjVQU0wK12tIuhEAHRwFaTHA%20DIo4QY8hrDbbYC7FKvY5gACum02ZBuMDuDyeLyOMCpNLp31%20mH%20-H4QA).

**How could I write this so that I can only use keys inside those defined types, but without the obligation to have all the keys used?**

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wvx5nN) work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably [mapping modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) is the thing you're looking for.

In your playground, just add two question marks as below:

```
type MyNewDictionary = {
  [pKey in AbcTypes]?: {
    [eKey in DefTypes]?: {
      onClick: () => void;
      onCancel: () => void;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't think of question marks not for a second, even I use them everyday. Thank you so much, it works!

Comment: Yeah, I tried but it needs to pass 20 minutes before I can accept it. I accepted it now! Thank you so much!